# How to convert column number into a letter

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a query formula via script. I have a dialogue which I would like to list all the available columns that have data in them. I can easily get the number of columns that the sheet has using `sheet.getLastColumn();`, but how can I easily convert that to the column format A,B,C...AA,BB,CC,... ?

So if the number of columns is 5 I am trying to get an array [A,B,C,D,E]  If it is 30 then I would expect an array of [A,B,C,...,CC].

Not sure why it is not letting me post, but I thought I would write some more to see if it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found this code somewhere:

```
function NUM_RETURN_LETRA(column){
  var temp, letter = '';
  while (column > 0)
  {
    temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}
```

Then for your case:

```
var columns = [];
for( i = 0; i< 10; i++)
  columns.push(NUM_RETURN_LETRA(+i));

return columns
```

Comment: Not sure I follow the logic of the NUM_RETURN_LETRA function but it works awesome.   I had to do a quick modification to the for statement:    for( i = 1; i<= column; i++).   Thank you

Comment: Don't try to "follow the logic" of calculations with '65'. Refers to the Unicode value ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode
'A' = 64, so you have an offset of 1.